# The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: ssl, blazor

Mientras le hacia pruebas a mis soluciones web me encontre con este tipo de error, este error no me sucedia cuando ejecutaba las soluciones en Visual Studio 2019 ya que cuando se ejecutaban la conexion era segura, sino que el error me sucedia cuando el servidor(Blazor Server) trataba de comunicarle algun mensaje al cliente(Blazor WebAssembly), el cliente se conectaba sin ningun problema al `Hub` del Blazor Server, pero cuando lo hacia con el protocolo Http sin el certificado SSL no permitia que el cliente recibiera el mensaje. NOTA: El "Cliente" fue creado con BlazorWebAssembly y NO esta hosteado, son dos soluciones diferentes que interactuan entre si por WebSockets.

Mi codigo:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await ConnectToServer();
}

public async Task ConnectToServer()
{
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(Globals.SignaR_Zones).Build();
    connectionStatus = "Connected"; isConnected = true;
    _connection.Closed += async (s) =>
    {
        isConnected = false;
        connectionStatus = "Disconnected";
        await _connection.StartAsync();
        isConnected = true;
    };

    _connection.On<string>("realtime", m =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });

    await _connection.StartAsync();
    Show(Toaster, MatToastType.Success, "Your are now connected", "Connection");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar este tipo de problema fue relativamente facil, antes de ejecutar el metodo que hace que el cliente se conecte al servidor llamado `ConnectToServer()` ejecutaba un metodo que basicamente le hacia un Bypass al certificado SSL. Este metodo lo coloque dentro del cliente en **Program.cs**, de ahi lo llamo de donde lo necesite, en este caso desde `App.razor` (es donde se inicializa el metodo `ConnectToServer()`).

```
//SSL
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public static void BypassCertificateError()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=

            delegate (
                Object sender1,
                X509Certificate certificate,
                X509Chain chain,
                SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                return true;
            };
    }
```

Quedaria asi:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   Program.BypassCertificateError(); // <------------- SOLO AGREGAR ESTO
   await ConnectToServer();
}

public async Task ConnectToServer()
{
  _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(Globals.SignaR_Zones).Build();
  connectionStatus = "Connected"; isConnected = true;
  _connection.Closed += async (s) =>
  {
    isConnected = false;
    connectionStatus = "Disconnected";
    await _connection.StartAsync();
    isConnected = true;
 };

_connection.On<string>("realtime", m =>
{
    StateHasChanged();
});

await _connection.StartAsync();
Show(Toaster, MatToastType.Success, "Your are now connected", "Connection");
}
```

Si no funciona de esa forma trata agregandolo antes de `connection.On`
[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109186/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-errors-when-calling-web-services-in-net)